# Popup doesnt show when using mysqli

Tags: jquery, popup

I'm creating a form, where the results should be showed in a popup.

The query works, but when I combine it with the popup it doesn't.
When I use the popup script alone it doesn't show the popup.

So I quess the problem is with the popup.

```
//javascript
$main .=
'<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>';
//end javascript
```

-

```
//script
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dialog").dialog({

      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $("#select-button").click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});

</script>
```

-

```
//form
 $main .= "
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <span class='formInput'>zoek:</span>
        <input type='text' name='zoekproduct' />
        <input id='select-button' type='submit' name='searchBtn' value='zoek!' />
    </form>"; 
// end form
```

-

```
// when used the button
    if(isset($_POST['searchBtn']))
    {
// query
    $statement = $connectionwebshop->prepare("
    SELECT 
        producten.productlink,
        prod_omschrijving.producttitel
    FROM
        producten
    INNER JOIN
        prod_omschrijving 
    ON
        producten.idproduct=prod_omschrijving.idproduct
    INNER JOIN
        prod_categorie
    ON
        producten.idproduct=prod_categorie.idproduct
    WHERE
        (producten.productlink LIKE ?
    OR
        prod_omschrijving.producttitel like ?
    OR
        producten.productcode like ?)
    AND
        prod_categorie.idcategorieen != 8001
    ORDER BY
        prod_omschrijving.producttitel
    ");
    $statement->error;
    $zoekproductresult ='%'.$_POST['zoekproduct'].'%';
    $statement->bind_param('sss', $zoekproductresult, $zoekproductresult, $zoekproductresult);
    $statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
//end query
```

-

```
//create popup
$main .='   
<div id="dialog" title="Resultaten selecteren" style="display: none">';
            if(($result->num_rows)>=1)
            {
            $resultaten = 'Found '.($result->num_rows).' products.<br/>';

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                $resultaten.= $row['producttitel'];
                $resultaten.='<br/>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
            $resultaten ='nothing found';
            }
        $main .= $resultaten;
    $statement->close();
    $main .='</div>';
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to use jQuery UI dialog?

Comment: yes, I found this the jQuery UI on internet.

Comment: where's the js that you call to open the dialogue?

Comment: what does displaying a popup have to do with db queries? You should be displaying client side code for client side problems. What does source look like?

Comment: Sorry forgot to copy that part of the script, I edited the begin post.

Comment: Can't tie the popup to the form submit button if you aren't using ajax to submit form and preventing page reresh caused by form submit

Comment: Come on, "Here is the code, fix it for me" is not a question to be asked on this site

Comment: charlietfl ok thank you, I can work with that I think. I did not know in what direction I should be looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the form if you want your popup to show (otherwise your page will reload).

Try this:

```
$("#select-button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#dialog").dialog( "open" );

  // Post your stuff
  $.ajax({
      url: 'form url here',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'zoekproduct=' + $('#zoekproduct').val(), // Give your zoekproduct input an id
      success: function (result) {
          // Do success stuff here
      }
  });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5DjMH/)

Answer (score 0):

The script has to be opened after the

```
<div id="dialog" title="Resultaten selecteren" style="display: none">';
```

So you will have this:

```
//create popup
$main .='   
<div id="dialog" title="Resultaten selecteren" style="display: none">';

//script
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dialog").dialog({

      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $("#select-button").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );

});
</script>

            if(($result->num_rows)>=1)
            {
            $resultaten = 'Found '.($result->num_rows).' products.<br/>';

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                $resultaten.= $row['producttitel'];
                $resultaten.='<br/>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
            $resultaten ='nothing found';
            }
        $main .= $resultaten;
    $statement->close();
    $main .='</div>';
    }
```